# Passing data via OLE to existing Excel file - ABAP

Tags: excel, abap, ole

I'm trying to export several tables to an Excel file using OLE.

Right now, I'm developing the hole file (merging cells, borders, shades, places, etc..).

But I already have an empty file. Is it possible to use OLE to pass the data to the right places of an existing excel file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. Needed to use this:

```
* Start the application
  create object e_appl 'EXCEL.APPLICATION'.
  set property of e_appl 'VISIBLE' = 1.

* Open the file
  call method of e_appl 'WORKBOOKS' = e_work.

  call method of e_work 'OPEN'
          exporting
               #1 = p_file.
```

Thank you.